# How to retrieve an [object Object] value in a Twitter API response

Tags: javascript, json, api, object, twitter

I'm currently using a twitter API (twit npm package) and I am currently getting a response with the structure like so

```
{ metadata: [Object],                                                                                                                                                                         
I20150213-22:24:29.155(0)?        created_at: 'Fri Feb 13 22:24:07 +0000 2015',                                                                                                                                               
I20150213-22:24:29.156(0)?        id: 566362206468845600,                                                                                                                                                                     
I20150213-22:24:29.156(0)?        id_str: '566362206468845569',                                                                                                                                                               
I20150213-22:24:29.157(0)?        text: 'Photo: New BTS picture from Mockingjay part  http://t.co/fo30mcLRYV',                                                                                                                
I20150213-22:24:29.158(0)?        source: '<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/" rel="nofollow">Tumblr</a>',                                                                                                                       
I20150213-22:24:29.158(0)?        truncated: false,                                                                                                                                                                           
I20150213-22:24:29.159(0)?        in_reply_to_status_id: null,                                                                                                                                                                
I20150213-22:24:29.159(0)?        in_reply_to_status_id_str: null,                                                                                                                                                            
I20150213-22:24:29.160(0)?        in_reply_to_user_id: null,                                                                                                                                                                  
I20150213-22:24:29.160(0)?        in_reply_to_user_id_str: null,                                                                                                                                                              
I20150213-22:24:29.161(0)?        in_reply_to_screen_name: null,                                                                                                                                                              
I20150213-22:24:29.161(0)?        user: [Object],                                                                                                                                                                             
I20150213-22:24:29.162(0)?        geo: null,                                                                                                                                                                                  
I20150213-22:24:29.162(0)?        coordinates: null,                                                                                                                                                                          
I20150213-22:24:29.163(0)?        place: null,                                                                                                                                                                                
I20150213-22:24:29.163(0)?        contributors: null,                                                                                                                                                                         
I20150213-22:24:29.164(0)?        retweet_count: 0,                                                                                                                                                                           
I20150213-22:24:29.288(0)?        favorite_count: 0,                                                                                                                                                                          
I20150213-22:24:29.289(0)?        entities: [Object],                                                                                                                                                                         
I20150213-22:24:29.289(0)?        favorited: false,                                                                                                                                                                           
I20150213-22:24:29.290(0)?        retweeted: false,                                                                                                                                                                           
I20150213-22:24:29.290(0)?        possibly_sensitive: false,                                                                                                                                                                  
I20150213-22:24:29.291(0)?        lang: 'en' },
```

I am trying to retrieve the entities object to access the potential media items inside it however when I console.log() the entities key in this Array  `[object Object]` gets logged. How do I access the inside of the object? I intend to extract a picture url from inside this object but I can't see whats inside. According to the Twitter API website media is stored inside entities objects.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think pretty much all browser consoles allow you to click onto such an `[object Object]` thingie to see actual property structure below it …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL's to the image is stored inside the entity `media` in the JSON response the REST call returns.

Say you want to access the `media_url` entity, simply access it as below

```
var result = the result from your call...
var imageUrl = result.entities.media.media_url;
```

and use the media URL in whatever way you want.

If you want to check the existence of media content, simply use `if(result.entities.media.length > 0)`.

Comment: And would there be a way to make sure that the tweet object has something inside media_url before assigning it to a variable? Because if it doesn't I'm getting an error back.

Comment: For some reason every time I try to log the media_url in the way you specified it still says its undefined. 
console.log(imageUrl.media_url);
But it has no problem just outputting
console.log(result.entities.media) and showing the media object. Do you have any idea why this is?

Comment: Two reasons may cause this; a) You have a typo somewhere in the variable names, or b) The `media_url` entity is `undefined`. Are you sure there actually is a media entity returned? What browser are you using? Why not just put a breakpoint in the code and check what the result returns?